# WFA: How to add field in checkedListBox from <vector>

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++

I've written the following code:

```
this->checkedListBox1->Items->Insert(0, "Copenhagen");
MyClass * tmp = new MyClasss();
std::vector <Element> AA = tmp->getAllEl();
Element mm = AA.front();
this->checkedListBox1->Items->Insert(1, mm.name);
```

but it tells me that:

```
cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string' to 'System::Object ^'
```

How can I convert `std::string` to `System::Object ^` ? Or how else can I insert Items in checkedListBox?

Comment: is it `String` or `string`? I think you mean `string`!

Answer (score 0):

You should convert you `std::string` to `System::String^`, then pass the `System::String^` and it will be acceptable.

This is how to make a `System::String ^` from an `std::string`:

```
String ^ S = gcnew String(mm.name.c_str());
```

Then pass it:

```
this->checkedListBox1->Items->Insert(1,S);
```

This should work for you.